# -sen for -self in English: history and usage

Tags: etymology, pronouns, dialects, reflexives

In my class there is a gentleman from the north of England who uses "-sen" instead of "-self" in such words as "himself" ("himsen") and "myself" ("mysen").

As far as I can tell, he always uses "-sen" in speech, it is not occasional.

I have never encountered this before and was wondering about its history/etymology and prevalence.

Comment: Also common in North and East Yorkshire

Answer (score 25):

It appears to be a dialectal variant from [East Midlands](https://books.google.it/books?id=VQd2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=sen%20as%20dialectal%20variant%20of%20self&source=bl&ots=odRg-kOxOz&sig=LDUQnXOIYxc2WmAqPBTGk0Ysvrg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL0Ku_qKDfAhXCXCwKHZptAJ8Q6AEwCnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=sen%20as%20dialectal%20variant%20of%20self&f=false) where:

> Reflexive pronouns are characterized by the ***replacement of "self" with sen (from Middle English [seluen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Middle_English_personal_pronouns_(table)))***:
>
> ***Y'usen*** – Yourself, 
>   ***Mesen*** – Myself, 
>   ***Thisens*** – Themselves/Yourselves, 
>   ***Ussens*** – Ourselves

Example:

> - We sh'll ay to do it ussens. (We shall have to do it ourselves.)

From (East Midlands English by Natalie Braber, Jonnie Robins)

as well as a Yorkshire variant:

> The word self may become sen, e.g. yourself becomes thy sen, tha sen.

From (Petyt, Keith M. (1985), '[Dialect' and 'Accent' in Industrial West Yorkshire](https://books.google.it/books?id=0skjSvKRQb4C&redir_esc=y), John Benjamins Publishing)

[image]

(www.asgbi.org.uk)

Comment: It is certainly widely used in Sheffield, and I suspect in much of Yorkshire.

Comment: In Barnsley too.

Comment: Also in Derbyshire (E. Midlands). I occasionally use it myself when 'putting on' the local dialect.